# JMeter Java HEAP issue seen after finished test plan execution in Jmeter-maven-plugin

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-maven-plugin

JMeter Test seems to finish fine.

But the next output after "14:48:37 [info] Completed Test: FssBenchmark.jmx" is missing because of the heap issue.

Next lines should normally be,

```
[INFO] Test Results:
[INFO]  
[INFO] Tests Run: 1, Failures: 0
```

**Have increased heap to 2048.**
HEAP issue.

```
[INFO] summary +      3 in 00:00:05 =    0.6/s Avg:  1651 Min:     1 Max:  2810 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 53 Finished: 53
[INFO] summary =    100 in 00:03:15 =    0.5/s Avg:  3664 Min:     1 Max: 47594 Err:     0 (0.00%)
[INFO] Tidying up ...    @ Wed Sep 15 18:33:06 UTC 2021 (1631730786136)
[INFO] ... end of run
[INFO] Completed Test: FssBenchmark.jmx
[INFO]  
[INFO] Executing test: FssStreamTest.jmx
[INFO] Writing log file to: /integration-tests/target/jmeter/logs/FssStreamTest.jmx.log
[INFO] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[INFO] WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/integration-tests/target/jmeter/lib/xstream-1.4.9.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
[INFO] WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
[INFO] WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[INFO] WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Creating summariser <summary>
[INFO] Created the tree successfully using /integration-tests/target/jmeter/testFiles/FssStreamTest.jmx
[INFO] Starting the test @ Wed Sep 15 18:33:07 UTC 2021 (1631730787166)
[INFO] Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
[INFO] summary +     13 in 00:00:24 =    0.6/s Avg:  1721 Min:   534 Max:  3115 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 2 Finished: 1
[INFO] summary +     10 in 00:00:13 =    0.8/s Avg:  1273 Min:   535 Max:  2804 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 4 Finished: 4
[INFO] summary =     23 in 00:00:36 =    0.6/s Avg:  1526 Min:   534 Max:  3115 Err:     0 (0.00%)
[INFO] Tidying up ...    @ Wed Sep 15 18:33:43 UTC 2021 (1631730823796)
[INFO] ... end of run
[INFO] Completed Test: FssStreamTest.jmx
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jmeter-maven-plugin:2.1.0:results (default-cli) @ integration-tests ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:37 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-15T18:33:45Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Java heap space -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError
[INFO] Shutdown detected, destroying JMeter process...
[INFO] Shutdown detected, destroying JMeter process...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have not configured enough xmx memory for the JMeter process.  You can set the amount of memory allocated to the process in the configuration settings for the plugin like this:

```
<configuration>
  <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
    <xms>1024</xms>
    <xmx>1024</xmx>
    <arguments>
      <argument>-Xprof</argument>
      <argument>-Xfuture</argument>
    </arguments>
  </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
</configuration>
```

Link to the wiki that describes this is: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Configuring-the-jvm-that-the-jmeter-process-runs-in